# Easy way to find cell reference in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a spreadsheet with lots of VBA code in it.  Most cell references use numbers, e.g.

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(someRow, someColumn)
```

I am wondering if there is any easy way to find out exactly which cell is being referenced - is it possible to put a breakpoint on this line of code, and then see which cell it will refer to (using the traditional "BA10" style) or will I have to calculate it each and every time using *divs* and *mods*?

Not all the references are hard coded, and I would really like to be able to work out where data is being pulled from, as the cell is accessed (not necessarily changed).

(edit) Is it possible to do this without changing the original source line, e.g. in an event module or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another option. If you are making changes to a sheet, you can catch the Change event on the Worksheet, and pump out the changed range like so:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Debug.Print "CHANGED -> " & Target.Address(False, False)
End Sub
```

Each change to the sheet will be output to your Immediate window like thus:

```
CHANGED -> G10
CHANGED -> G11:G28
```

There is also the SelectionChange event as well, but that's unlikely to be too useful. There is no event for just "reading" cells.

Answer (score 5):

```
Debug.Print Worksheets(1).Cells(10, 53).Address(False, False)
```

returns BA10

Answer (score 2):

You can use Address.

Debug.print Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(10, 53).Address

Will print the ranges address for you in the Immediate Window.

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: sort of, but doing this would mean I have to use multiple statements or change the variable names each time - is there a way to do it automatically based on what will be executed next?

Comment: This is the best way to do it. There is no automatic way to do what you want. But you can use your variables "Debug.Print iColumn".

Answer (score 1):

You can also change your reference style to R1C1 in:
tools\options\general\R1C1 reference style
this way you will be able to know what the code is refereeing to.

Comment: This does make it easier to see which cell is being referred to, but I still have to use watches or something to be able to find out what the cell reference is

Answer (score 1):

Another way to go would be to add a watch in the VBE (Visual Basic Editor). You can do this by going to View>Watch Window to make sure the watch window is visible. Then from Debug menu click Add Watch. If you do this in break mode the context will already be set for you so all you have to do is paste in the expression you want watched and it will be visible. This of course works best on range objects (ex: rngFoo.Address as the expression) but you can paste in things like Worksheets(1).Cells(10, 53).Address.

Comment: Yeah, this would work except I would have to set up lots of different watches because there are lots of different variables used at different places through the code - it seems a bit pointless to watch all the variables when I am only interested in what the current line will evaluate to, but I don't want to have add a new watch every time

Comment: I understand, the only other way I know is to drop out to the immediate window: Ctrl-G and use the print char "?" to see what it evaluates to. Example: ?Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(10, 53).Address

Comment: You know that when in break mode you can hover over a variable name in the code to see what it evaluates to without needing to set a watch, right?

Comment: When in debug mode, You can hover over any variable in current line, and see what values they have. Or which one caused some error.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following to know which cell is calling the function:

```
Application.Caller.Address
```

Example:

```
Function Addition(va As Double, vb As Double) As Double
    Addition = va + vb
    MsgBox "Cell calling function Addition is " & Application.Caller.Address
End Function
```

Whenever this function is calculated a message box indicates the cell address calling it.
Be aware that calling this function from another VBA function will send an error. Check http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx